# Add index to running MongoDB container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a running Docker container, whose image was built from `Dockerfile` and `index.js` below:

```
FROM mongo

COPY indexes.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

```
const db = new Mongo().getDB('test');
db.getCollection('testcollection').createIndex({key0: 1, key1: 1});
```

Now I need another index, say `{key0: 1, key2: -1}`.  I added `createIndex` call to my `index.js` but according to [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) it is called only when a container is started **for the first time**.  How can I apply this setting to my **already running** container, preserving the data?

**ADDED:**
My `docker-compose.yml` has the following:

```
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${mongouser}
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${mongopass}
```

So I `docker exec .. mongo`ed and then did

```
use test
db.auth(THE_VALUES_FOR_ABOVE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES)
```

which resulted in `Error: Authentication failed.`.

Now I have two problems:

- What's the right credential to use to authenticate for adding indexes?
- Given that I control the image, is there simpler way?

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding the situation correctly, is that some reason that you cannot run createIndex() in the mongo shell after the instance has been started..?

Comment: @Ray, you're right.  I've added some description.

Comment: Have you tried adding --authenticationDatabase, --username, --password option when you execute mongo? Ref : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase

Comment: Usually user are created in `admin` database. Switch to db `admin` before you authenticate or authenticate directly when you connect to MongoDB

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.  I'm still looking for more automated way though.